# Domain of $f(x)=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{\tan(x)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I have to evaluate the domain of

$$f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\mbox{sgn}(x)}{\tan(x)}$$

where $\mbox{sgn}(x)$ is the signum function.

The condition that define the domain is

$$\tan(x)\ne 0 \implies \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\ne 0 \implies \sin(x)\ne 0\ \vee \ \cos(x)\ne 0$$

so the domain must be

$\mbox{Dom}(f)=\mathbb{R}-\left\{k\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right\}\ \ \mbox{with} \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$

but Wolfram doesn't agree with my solution. I need to understand where is my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\tan(x)=0 \implies x= k\pi$$

and doesn't exist tangent at the point $\frac \pi 2 + k \pi$

Comment: That's true,  but $\tan(x)\ne 0$ is different... $\tan(x)$ must exist  to solve the inequality $\tan(x)\ne 0$

Comment: @Ixion: what is the relation between the solution that I gave you and the solution that you need?

Comment: Oh, I see now! The solution you get is equivalent to my solution! Sorry, I lost your edit.

Comment: So, is Wolfram's solution wrong? :|